# how to make a java program run on remote machine such that its logged messages are made available to me

Tags: java

I want to run a java program on a remote machine.

Also, I want all of the log messages which are logged by that program, to be available to me in another machine. A plus would be if I could filter/receive messages of a certain type, eg DEBUG messages/ ERROR messages only.

Is this possible? I dont want to change the code of the program that will actually be run on the remote machine.

Comment: You can't connect to the remote machine using something like ssh and view the logs?

Comment: @Jon a lot of times you want logs from various sources to be compiled into one master log, or put into some kind of data warehouse.

Comment: Is the program using something like log4j?  You could make sure it logs to stdout and then pipe that to a program that takes input from stdin and sends it to another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syslog is a remote logging system, allowing you to generate logging messages on one machine, and receive them on another:

- run a syslog daemon on the machine you want to receive log mesages on
- for your Java program, use a logging framework which supports syslog, and configure it to send messages to your syslog daemon.  For example, log4j supports pluggable "appenders", and a syslog appender exists for log4j.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to change the code, you can always open up a socket to your home server and log the messages over the wire.

If you're not willing to change the local code you need an external process to either intercept the output streams of the program, or to keep a watch on its output logs. In both of those cases, it just opens a socket home and sends the data.